# Can I download an apk of an app I have payed for?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

So my dilemma is that I paid for Minecraft PE some years ago, but then I deleted my Google Play Store account, and got a **new one**.

- What I'm wondering is if it is okay to download the apk because I'm not paying for it again, and I think it would because technically an apk file is kind of like a rom backup of a cartridge game and those are legal to download if you own a legal version of the game
- My issue is that I'm downloading the apk of the newer update then I bought, so is it legal? Since the version of game is different from what I have purchased

Answer (score 2):

Since you have changed the account from the one from which you purchased the app and are now using a different account , you **cannot**" use the app purchased. Purchases are tied to the account

**Use of a product purchased in one account in a different account**

[Add Google Play Apps from Other Google Account?](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-transfer-your-Google-Play-purchases-to-another-account)

As You can see in the discussion, you cannot. Google play purchases are tied to the account from which you have purchased and can't be transferred

[Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/UgCgeNHYf04) says the same

Second part of your question is not relevant because you can't use the app purchased under a different account

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted your account, you've also dropped everything connected to it. So no, there's no legal way to "download and use that APK" – as the license was bound to your deleted account. You could ask the dev to *transfer* your license to your new account – but how you prove you're the owner of the old one, and indeed have paid for the license, is between the two of you. The dev is in no way obligated to comply: if he does so, it's just out of goodwill.